# Guice - how to inject abstract field in parent from child

Tags: dependency-injection, abstract-class, guice

I have a simple hierarchy like follows:

```
public abstract class AbsFoo {
    protected AbsBoo boo;
}

public class Foo extends AbsFoo {
    public Foo() {
        boo = new Boo(); // Boo extends AbsBoo
    }
}
```

EDIT: Instances of AbsFoo should be created on the fly and may not be fields

Can I replace `boo = new Boo()` with injection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes:

```
public abstract class AbsFoo {
    protected AbsBoo boo;
}

public class Foo extends AbsFoo {
    @Inject
    public Foo(Boo boo) {
        super.boo = boo; // Boo extends AbsBoo
    }
}
```

Make sure you construct your Foo instance with @Inject or injector.getInstance()

**Edit**

You can also use a provider to create instances on demand:

```
@Inject
Provider<Foo> fooProvider

//...

public void doSomething(){
    //need new foo:
    Foo foo = fooProvider.get();
}
```

Comment: Well - the problem is then AbsBoo and its children have to be exposed to the outside world. I want to avoid this. Foo knows it needs Boo and no one else needs to know

Comment: How does this expose AbsBoo to the outside world?

Comment: I think I'm missing important piece of information here. Foo needs to be created dynamically. I was using "AbsFoo foo = new Foo()" so I don't want to do "AbsFoo foo = new Foo(new Boo()) if I can help it

Comment: I guess I need to read more about Providers. Say I have a class that creates various flavors of AbsFoo, does it mean that I have specify multiple providers to match each flavor? Can I encapsulate that in some sort of factory?

Comment: The standard guice way is to inject multiple provides... one provider per class you want.  If you want to encapsulate that into one super-factory class, you can, but it is probably unnecessary.  The good news is that you aren't writing a provider per class, you just need to specify the generic parameter in the provider declaration: Provider<Foo> fooProvider and guice will do the rest.

Answer (score 2):

As long as Boo itself isn't abstract you should be able to.

```
public class Foo extends AbsFoo {

    @Inject
    public Foo( AbsBoo boo ) {
        this.boo = boo;
    }
}

public class FooModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override 
  protected void configure() {
    bind(AbsBoo.class).to(Boo.class);
    bind(AbsFoo.class).to(Foo.class);
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new FooModule());
    AbsFoo foo = injector.getInstance(AbsFoo.class);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Will this work if I need to produce multiple instances of various AbsFoo implementations?

Comment: @Bostone - not really.  you're probably better off using a factory at that point and injecting the proper dependencies needed by each implementation.